# Show that $2x^2 + 4$ is reducible in $\Bbb C$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that $2x^2 + 4$ is reducible in $\Bbb C$.

By the definition of irreducible, $2x^2 + 4$ is reducible if I can find $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that $2x^2 + 4 = f(x)g(x)$ and $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both not units.  But I can't seem to find a non-unit product of $2x^2 + 4$ in $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{Q}[i]$? since all polynomials are trivially reducible over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Is your polynomial $2x^2+4$ or $2x^2+2$? One is irreducible, the other is reducible.

Comment: Edited for clarity, it's $2x^2 + 4$.

Comment: $$2x^2+4=(\sqrt2x)^2-(2i)^2=(\sqrt2x-2i)(\sqrt2x+2i)$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A polynomial of degree $2$ over a field (like $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$) is reducible exactly when it has a root.

In your case the polynomial does have a root in $\mathbb{C}$ so it is reducible.

$$
2x^2 + 4 = 2(x- i\sqrt{2})(x + i\sqrt{2})
$$

In fact the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra states that all polynomials over $\mathbb{C}$ are reducible if their degree is greater than $1$.

If you consider the polynomial over $\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{Q}$), then the polynomial is irreducible because it does not have any roots.

Answer (score 2):

You have

$$2x^2+4=2(x-i\sqrt 2)(x+i\sqrt 2)$$

so it is reducible on $\mathbb C$.

Comment: but as is stated in the definition for reducibility, when making factors both factors should not be a unit, but the 2 is a unit right? is a third factor, does that make the difference? why?

Answer (score 2):

Observe that by the fundamental theorem of algebra every polynomial $P(x)$ of degree $n$ contains $n$ roots (counting multiplicity) in $\mathbb{C}$.

So we go ahead and compute the roots

$$ 2x^2 + 4 = 0 \rightarrow x^2 + 2 = 0 \rightarrow x = \pm i \sqrt{2} $$

Thus $2(x - i\sqrt{2}) (x + i\sqrt{2})$ is a factorization of this polynomial over $\mathbb{C}$

Answer (score -3):

- polynomial over C[x] does not have a unit when x is put to be roots...
  As 2(x-i√2)(x+i√2) for x to be +-i√2 factors are not unit over C[x]